# Using ranges::copy_if versus using iterator constructor with views::filter

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I noticed that I can seemingly get the same logic(copy elements matching some predicate into `vector`) both using `ranges::copy_if` and also using vector constructor taking 2 iterators(by providing it with `filter_view` .begin() and .end()).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

const std::vector<int> vals{1,2,3,47,8472};
const auto filter_pred = [](const int i){return i%2==0;};

void fna(){
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::ranges::copy_if(vals, std::back_inserter(result), filter_pred);
    std::cout << fmt::format("{}", result) << std::endl;
}

void fn1(){
    auto filtered = vals | std::views::filter(filter_pred);
    std::vector<int> result {filtered.begin(), filtered.end()};
    std::cout << fmt::format("{}", result) << std::endl;
}

std::vector<int> fna_val(){
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::ranges::copy_if(vals, std::back_inserter(result), filter_pred);
    return result;
}

std::vector<int> fn1_val(){
    auto filtered = vals | std::views::filter(filter_pred);
    return {filtered.begin(), filtered.end()};
}

int main(){
    fna();
    fn1();
    std::cout << fmt::format("{}", fna_val()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fmt::format("{}", fn1_val()) << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a reason to prefer one over other?
What I can think of:

- it is unlikely that either is more efficient, since I doubt that any real optimizations can be done since because  _if in `copy_if` means  destination size is unknown.
- compile speed: `copy_if` could be faster to compile since it does not require `<ranges>` header, but did not benchmark
- const all the things: `copy_if` requires mutable destination container, range construction does not
- verbosity: when return type of function is known we do not need to spell out the `std::vector` in body, `{}` works. Would be nice if vector understood ranges so we would not have to use `.begin()` `.end()`, but it does not.

Comment: @康桓瑋 https://godbolt.org/z/K51P8vPMz Maybe I messed up something when c/p but code seems to compile.

Comment: What I mean is that when `vals` is `views::iota(0) | views::take(5)`, `fn1()` will not work because the `vector` must accept the iterator-pairs of *same* types.

Comment: @康桓瑋 ah true, it does not work for ranges that are not https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/common_range... great point.